# Validates_format_of?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
1 error prohibited this {{model}} from being saved

  There were problems with the following fields:

    * {{attribute}} {{message}}
```

I am getting this error and code I am using is:

```
validates_format_of :user_id , :with => /\A(([0-9]{4})-[A-Z]{2}$)\Z/ , :message => "should be in the format 1111-TT", :allow_nil => true, :allow_blank => true
```

Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: I'm confused by your question.  What error are you getting, and where/when do you get it?  For example, what was given as the value of user_id, to trigger the validation fail?  I don't know if `* {{attribute}} {{message}}` is your attempt to describe the message in abstract terms, or the actual error.  Or something else.  It's confusing.

Comment: All I want if I enter anything in user_id( if not validate) then it should give me message "should be in the format 1111-TT"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem using Rails 2 and i18n 0.5.0.  Uninstall i18n 0.5.0 or specify the older version (I'm using 0.4.1) in your environment.